# Which airplane has the biggest ratio of Vne to stall speed?

Tags: aircraft-performance

Of airplanes that cannot hover (rotorcraft, VTOL), which one has the biggest ratio of $V_{NE}$ (speed that it may never exceed) to stall speed?

To be precise, "stall speed" here means the slowest horizontal speed at which it can avoid descending long-term.  Whether or not the wing is technically stalled.  Long-term implies powered, so no gliders.  Not in ground effect.

**Edit:** both speeds are roughly **at ground level**, for fairer competition as Peter suggested.
That low, $V_{NE}$ for an otherwise supersonic jet may not be obvious.

A few *estimated* starting points:

- Fieseler Storch, 109 mph / 31 mph = 3.5
- SR-71A, 790(?) mph / 180 mph = 4.4
- Carbon Cub SS, 141 mph / 31 mph = 4.5
- Pilatus PC-24, 500(?) kts / 83 kts = 6.0
- Antonov AN-2, 160 mph / 25(?) mph = 6.4

Comment: You should restrict the speeds to ground level. That takes the cheaters like SR-71 out of the picture and gives a fairer competition.

Comment: I PC-24 Vne truely 500 kts at low altitude?

Comment: @Jpe61 probably not.  These numbers are just a rough starting point.

Comment: Who deleted the comments?

Comment: Pilots report a "stall" speed of the AN-2 of 30 mph.  Maybe even 25 mph. Please correct your table.

Comment: Vne is a design speed with no guarantee that it is achievable in level flight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the following flight envelope ([source](https://forum.dcs.world/topic/105452-test-data-level-flight-envelope)), at sea level the F-15 has a maximum speed of Mach 1.2 and a stall speed (at $C_{L_{MAX}}$) of Mach 0.1, giving a ratio of 12.

[image: F-15 flight envelope]

The F-14 comes close ([source](https://heatblur.se/fmupdate/)) with a maximum speed of almost Mach 1.3 and a stall speed of Mach 0.15, giving a ratio of 8.6.

[image: F-14 flight envelope]

Comment: Nice!  But before accepting, I'll wait a bit longer for other answers.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Yes wait please: I'm checking all of the teen series jet fighters which are all good candidates actually

Comment: Don't forget the F-111. Like most of these, the hard part is finding the stall speed. You also have to consider aircraft weight. It doesn't affect Vne that much, but some a/c have an over 2:1 ratio between MTOW and no armament/low fuel weights. That has a significant impact on stall speed.

Comment: @Gerry I also thought about the F-111 but I couldn't find any official data

Answer (score 4):

A good candidate is an airplane which has good high-lift devices for landing while being designed to go fast at low level. A swing wing helps, too.

So I propose the B-1A or B-1B Lancer. Specs are hard to find and the [Air Force Fact Sheet](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104500/b-1b-lancer/) gives Mach 1.2 at sea level as the top speed but neglects to mention stall speed.

[Here](http://aviationarchives.blogspot.com/2017/09/rockwell-b-1-lancer-flight-manual.html) a downloadable copy of a preliminary version of the B-1A flight manual is offered but weighs in at 458.2 MB. The only low speed limit mentioned is an approach speed of 140 KIAS at 220,000 lbs. Angle of attack limits are given as fractions on an AoA meter and approach AoA is 0.7 units. Assuming that stall AoA is 1, this means that approach is flown at 1.2 times v$_{stall}$, which looks about right. This would bring stall speed down to 117 KIAS. Mach 1.2 at ground level, on the other hand, is 1.2$\cdot$340 m/s or 793 KIAS at standard atmospheric conditions.

The ratio between 117 and 793 KIAS is 6.78.

If we want to cheat a little, we fly Mach 1.2 in very cold air (say -20°C) which brings the speed of sound to 620 knots and top speed to 744 knots. Now we need to reduce stall speed, too, by the [increased density](https://www.engineersedge.com/physics/speed_of_sound_13241.htm) of 113.8% of standard density to 102.8 knots.

The ratio between 102.8 and 744 knots is 7.24.

Answer (score 1):

Re "of airplanes that cannot hover" -- if you are at all familiar with "3D" model-airplane flying you will have seen all kinds of videos of maneuvers involving airplanes hanging on their props with zero airspeed. Well, that's a hover, but a similar airplane with *slightly* less power could do *essentially* the same thing, nose almost straight up, but creeping forward horizontally at say 0.1 mph to provide a *slight* amount of lift from the (obviously stalled) wing.  So any of these "3D" hover-capable model airplanes, if provided with some sort of power limiter to prevent true hovering, could meet your criteria, if they were eligible.

Moving on, assuming you are only interested in full-scale manned aircraft--

We also have the issue of how much airspeed is needed to provide controllability.  Factors to consider-- is there a propwash over the control surfaces, and if not, are there thrust-vectoring jet nozzles?

So, the caveat "cannot hover" fails to eliminate planes that can *almost* hover, and in the world of thrust vectoring etc there are several full-scale aircraft, including jets with thrust-vectoring exhaust nozzles like the Su-35, that cannot *truly* hover in a sustained fashion<sup>1</sup> but can do sustained post-stall maneuvers involving *extremely* low forward airspeeds. And since your question stated "Whether or not the wing is technically stalled", it's got to be some thrust-vectoring military jet like a Su-35 capable of sustained, extreme, post-stall maneuvers that will take the prize.<sup>2,3</sup>

Footnotes:

1. The Su-35 has enough *thrust* to hover with the nose straight up at zero airspeed, but would not be controllable enough to allow this maneuver to be sustained indefinitely.
2. Model airplanes appear to be well ahead of full-scale airplanes in this area too.  I've seen electric ducted fan scale models of various military jets, with the addition of vectored thrust exhaust nozzles that may or may not have been present on the full-scale versions, flown in a sustained manner in constant-altitude flight at truly extreme nose-high pitch attitudes and extremely low airspeeds.  In contrast, in the Wikipedia page on the full-scale "Cobra" maneuver ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_maneuver ), we read "To perform the cobra, the maneuver must be entered from fairly high subsonic speeds. Proper entry speed is necessary because, if the maneuver is entered too slowly, the plane might be unable to complete the maneuver or return to level flight with sufficient speed."  Nonetheless I still believe a vectored-thrust military jet capable of extreme post-stall maneuvers is a good candidate for your criteria.
3. To the best of my knowledge, due to scaling issues, full-scale manned sport aerobatic airplanes cannot do the hovering 3-D maneuvers described in the first paragraph of this answer.  If that's incorrect, or becomes incorrect in the future, then such an aircraft, fitted with some sort of power limiter to prevent true hovering but to allow sustained flight with the nose almost straight up and the forward airspeed in the 1-2 mph range or less, would appear to be an even better candidate for your criteria than a thrust-vectoring jet like a Su-35.

Comment: Good analysis of this "almost rotorcraft" boundary where the denominator gets too small, analogous to Peter's "only near ground level" fix for where the numerator gets too large.  (Such "3D" models I've flown and even reviewed for the magazine that shared your username!)  But it's still puzzling how to avoid apples-vs-oranges.

Comment: If lift doesn't come from the wing rather from the propeller (or the jet), then it is not an airplane, by definition

Comment: @sophit it just has to have move slightly so that wing creates a tiny bit of lift at 89° AoA.

Answer (score -1):

The Antonov AN-2 [has no declared stall speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65718/what-makes-the-antonov-an-2-have-no-stall-speed). So even with a maximum speed of 258 km/h, it has an infinite ratio of stall speed to vne.

Rumours give the stall speed at 40 km/h. So a ratio of 6.5.

The Vought V-173 "Flying Pancake" was a prototype, it flew 190 times, pilots declared they could not stall it and it reached a max speed of 138 mph ... so it has a ratio of infinite.

Comment: Good answer, but -- "they could not stall it"-- but what was the lowest forward speed they were able to achieve?  Could they pull the nose all the way up to create a hover (which would disqualify the aircraft from the criteria of the question), or nearly so (doubtful, but maybe)-- it would be good to know the lowest horizontally forward airspeed that they were able to document --

Comment: PS I've heard similar claims for the "Draco" -- evidently it has so much power that you essentially just can't stall it even with the stick full back --  yet I doubt it could truly hover, or near-hover with 1 mph forward speed-- !

Comment: Please note this question's careful definition of "stall speed."

Comment: If speed is zero then lift if zero and there's no way that it's flying, unless it's a helicopter

Comment: The AN-2 "doesn't have a stall speed" in the sense that the tail doesn't have enough control authority to raise the AoA to the point of stalling, so an engine-out descent with the stick full aft will generate a forward speed above the stall speed.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune according to your definition, the stall speed of the AN2 is probably 25 mph (source:  "
Antonov An-2 Annushka, Maid of All Work" from Dmitriy Komissarov and Yefim Gordon